# Need Help, Cannot recover my Linux Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I had Dual Boot (Ubuntu/Windows7), installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS after windows 7 with the option in ubuntu's installation "Install Ubuntu alongside windows 7".
after 2 years of usage and less disk space I wanted to get rid of windows 7, so I used live USB of windows 7 and managed to delete the partition of windows to add space into my ubuntu, as soon as I had deleted the Windows C:/ partition, the Ubuntu's file system changed to 'unallocated', so I reinstalled my windows 7 again, since then I am unable to get my original ubuntu that contained soo many important files and installation. However a lot of research guided me through 
a) Using Lilo
b) Using Boot-Repair
c) Using Terminal
all by using Ubuntu Live CD. but all of them failed to recognize that ubuntu partition.

Moreover When I used Boot-Repair, it gave me [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11857124/) link to post it on ask ubuntu thread. so here I am. Please help me with this quickSand sinking my time badly.. Any kind of help is much much much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the windows installation options you choose, you might have blown the partition away, damaged, or formatted it.

If you boot up with a live cd and run gparted and the linux partition is no longer there, and all you see is unallocated space; I'm sorry to tell you , but it sounds like it's gone.

Comment: Moral of the story, backup your linux data before doing anything windows installation related. Never trust Microsoft. :-)

Answer (score 0):

i had a quick look at your report and it seems that you didn't delete all your data but what you had done with your drives, partitions and also filesystems seems a "little bit" chaotic...!

i would advice you to use [SuperGrub2Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) to boot into a maybe still present OS or use any Live-System, mount your drives, save your data on an external storage and perform a new clean install.